# Repeater + taxonomy: same value in every field

Tags: taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

Using repeater and taxonomy fields. Taxonomy values populate correcty but when changes are saved, same value is stored in every repeater field.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Page where values are stored is a blank template with no previous taxonomies selected.

Answer (score 2):

You have "Save Terms" enabled, which means that the field is controlling which taxonomy terms are attached to the post, not saving the term as a custom field, and because you also have "Load Terms" enabled, both fields are loading the terms attached to the post, which means that both fields load the same value. Turn both of these settings off.